# Pi Hole DNS not working after configuring Wireless Access Point on Arch Linux in Bridge Mode on Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, raspberry-pi, pi-hole

I'm experimenting with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (running arch linux) and its WLAN module.

Until today I had Pi Hole running on it for my entire network.
The Pi stands where we have very poor Wifi reception for mobile phones so I decided to add Wifi AP to the Pi.

Now the strange thing is that the WLAN AP is working perfectly (set up in bridged mode like described @ https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) but I can't do DNS requests to the Pi anymore.

```
dig pi.home @192.168.1.150
; <<>> DiG 9.13.5 <<>> pi.home @192.168.1.150
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Even more confusing is the fact that as soon I load the Pi Hole web interface  in Chrome once, DNS is working again.

I currently have the following configuration.

**Pi-Hole's DNS server listens on all interfaces**

**bridge configuration**

```
cat /etc/netctl/bridge
Description="WAP Bridge"
Interface=br0
Connection=bridge
BindsToInterfaces=(eth0 wlan0)
IP=no
ExecUpPost="ip link set dev br0 address $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address); IP=dhcp; ip_set"
ExecDownPre="IP=dhcp"
SkipForwardingDelay=yes
```

**iptables**

```
cat /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:196]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [88:10291]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [31:4764]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

**ifconfig**

```
ifconfig
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 xyxyxy  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xyxyxy  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2537  bytes 468919 (457.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 267  bytes 60665 (59.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 xyxyxy  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xyxyxy  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2560  bytes 473036 (461.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 297  bytes 70500 (68.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 109  bytes 8338 (8.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 109  bytes 8338 (8.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 xyxyxy  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xyxyxy  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2276  bytes 529781 (517.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**IPv4 forwarding**

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/ipv4forwarding.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**/etc/dhcpd.conf contains**

```
[...]
denyinterfaces eth0
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

**/etc/hotapd/hostapd.conf (if this is needed)**

```
cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=<SSID>
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=<PASSWORD>
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Anyone ideas? Can this be related to "permit all origins" in the DNS setting of Pi Hole?

Comment: Why do you have IP Forwarding rules when you're bridging?

Comment: @roaima I somehow thought this is still needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `Gateway` to `br0` and remove IPv4 forwarding and all `iptables` rules.